# QT Event filter for holding mouse button down

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How would I modify the filter to fire when the user presses and holds rather than just presses? I have something working, but it's not contained entirely in a filter, and it gets messy.  I can't figure out how to determine if the user is holding the button for some set time without blocking the UI thread

```
def holdable(widget):    
    class Filter(QObject):    
        clicked = pyqtSignal()        
        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):        
            if obj == widget:
                if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                    if obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                        self.clicked.emit()
                        return True
            return False    
    filter = Filter(widget)
    widget.installEventFilter(filter)
    return filter.clicked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't that hard once I thought about it, but here it is

```
def holdable(widget):
    class Filter(QObject):    
        clicked = pyqtSignal(QWidget)        
        def eventFilter(self, obj, event):        
            if obj == widget:
                if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                    if obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                        obj.heldDown = datetime.datetime.now()
                        #return True     
                elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                    if obj.rect().contains(event.pos()):
                        if(obj.heldDown):
                            diff = datetime.datetime.now() - obj.heldDown
                            obj.heldDown = None
                            if(diff.total_seconds() > 1):                                
                                self.clicked.emit(obj)
                                return True           
            return False    
    filter = Filter(widget)
    widget.installEventFilter(filter)
    return filter.clicked
```

and you would hook it onto a widget by doing this:

`holdable(widgetinstance).connect(self.holdingCallback)`